# What can one do to see clearer that God is really in charge of everything?

Tags: theology, mussar-ethics, faith-bitachon-emunah, hashgacha-pratit

Based on my Jewish learning it is clear that God created the world, oversees everything and everything that happens is in accord with his will.

However as I carry out my day to day activities it seems as if I and the "nature" of things is the cause of everything that happens in my environemnt. (e.g. if I speed, I get a ticket; if I work then I can support my family; if I neglect my health, I jeapordize my life; etc.)

What exactly may one do to see clearer that God is really in the picture?

Answer (score 4):

The Shulchan Aruch rules that one should always be in the habit of saying, "Everything the Merciful One does is for the best." (Orach Chaim 230:5; Berachos 60b). So we should say that throughout the day, whenever something happens. A shorter equivalent would be "gamzu l'tovah" from the Talmudic story of Nachum Gamzo. (Ta'anis 21a). Similarly, the Yerushalmi says that one should always say, "Lord of Hosts, Happy is the man who trusts in You." (Y. Berachos 5:1, 53b). This could have a similar effect, of reminding you to trust that Hashem is determining events, and doing everything for the best.

Another idea is to keep a "hashgacha pratis" journal, keeping daily notes of coincidences and other things that happen to you daily, which reinforce your belief in Providence. This could be as simple as an email you send yourself with a brief description, and whenever another thing happens, it can be a "Re:" email in response, helping you collect the recollections in one thread. Sooner or later, you will begin to notice such things on a daily basis.

Finally, see [this](http://www.azamra.org/Essential/knowing.htm) passage on "hints" Hashem sends us, and read these two chapters ([here](http://www.bilvavi.net/english/bilvavi-part-1-section-4-belief-divine-providence) and [here](http://www.bilvavi.net/english/bilvavi-part-2-chapter-11-divine-providencen)) from the Bilvavi on Divine Providence.

Comment: That email tip seems like a great idea! I usually use google docs for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

some suggestions

1. strengthen your faith in God and His torah.
2. study books which teach on the subject that God is in charge of everything such as the chovos halevavos shaar bitachon.
3. avoid reading things written by those who don't believe in these things